# dynamically hiding linkbuttons in a gridview

Tags: asp.net

Here is my template field with 2linkbuttons in a gridview. 
How do I hide one of the lnkbuttons depending on the user selection

```
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <table>
       <tr>

       <td align="center">
       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName= "Publish" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>"></asp:LinkButton>
       </td>

       <<td align="center">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"   CommandName= "Block" HeaderText="Block" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>">Block</asp:LinkButton>
       </td>

       </tr>
       </table>
       </ItemTemplate>

       </asp:TemplateField>       


protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {


   if(Status=="Posted")
   {
            LinkButton lbtn2 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton2");
            lbtn2.Visible = false;
    }
   if(Status=="Publish")
       {
                LinkButton lbtn1 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");
                lbtn1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

I am doing this using 2 linkbuttons in the template field.
Here if the Status == Posted, then hide LinkButton2. 
If ItemType == Published, then hide LinkButton1.

I don't mind using only Linkbutton and set the commandName and commandArgument in aspx.cs`

I am getting an error at...

```
LinkButton lbtn2 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton2");
lbtn2.Visible = false;
```

Error: Object reference not set to an instance pointing to lnbt2.Visible = false;

Any clues, 
Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 0):

Check to be sure that the row in question is a data row, not a header, etc. The issue is probably because the current row is a header or footer, so it doesn't contain your controls and throws an exception.

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if(Status=="Posted")
        {
            LinkButton lbtn2 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton2");
            lbtn2.Visible = false;
        }
        if(Status=="Publish")
        {
            LinkButton lbtn1 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");
            lbtn1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct. I moved the code to DataControlRowType.DataRow. I does not give me any error but the template field Action is blank with no Linkbuttons

Comment: @Sun: What is "Status" in your code sample? Is there some code that assigns that variable that you have removed? Or is Status a property on the object being databound? If you set a breakpoint in that event handler and look at the value of Status, what do you get?

Comment: Status is the ItemStatus. We have items which could be posted or published.

Comment: @Sun: It looks like you need to get the DataItem from the current row... I can give you some code for it, but I need to know if you are  binding to a custom object/class or to a data source (like the SqlDataSource)?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I was looking for the same thing; I was able to do it this way also and posting just for reference:

This is in a listview but should be same for gridview:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnForms" runat="server" Text='MyButton' CommandName="MyCommandName"
Style='<%#GetHiddenTag(Eval("Status").ToString())%>'  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Status")%>' OnClick="MyOnClickCodeBehind" />
```

Codebehind:

```
    public string GetHiddenTag(string Status)
    {
        if (Status.ToLower() == "completed")
            return "visibility:hidden;";

        return "visibility:visible;";
    }
```